# Playback when using Web Audio API skips at the beginning of every chunk

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've been building a music app and today I finally got around to the point where I started trying to work playing the music into it.

As an outline of how my environment is set up, I am storing the music files as MP3s which I have uploaded into a MongoDB database using GridFS.  I then use a socket.io server to download the chunks from the MongoDB database and send them as individual emits to the front end where the are processed by the Web Audio API and scheduled to play.

When they play, they are all in the correct order but there is this very tiny glitch or skip at the same spots every time (presumably between chunks) that I can't seem to get rid of.  As far as I can tell, they are all scheduled right up next to each other so I can't find a reason why there should be any sort of gap or overlap between them.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's the code:

**Socket Route**

```
socket.on('stream-audio', () => {
  db.client.db("dev").collection('music.files').findOne({"metadata.songId": "3"}).then((result) =>{
      const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db.client.db("dev"), {
        bucketName: "music"
      });
      bucket.openDownloadStream(result._id).on('data',(chunk) => {
      socket.emit('audio-chunk',chunk)
    });
  });
});
```

**Front end**

```
//These variable are declared as object variables, hence all of the "this" keywords
context: new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),
freeTime: null,
numChunks: 0,
chunkTracker: [],

...

this.socket.on('audio-chunk', (chunk) => {
      //Keeping track of chunk decoding status so that they don't get scheduled out of order
      const chunkId = this.numChunks
      this.chunkTracker.push({
        id: chunkId,
        complete: false,
      });
      this.numChunks += 1;

      //Callback to the decodeAudioData function
      const decodeCallback = (buffer) => {
        var shouldExecute = false;
        const trackIndex = this.chunkTracker.map((e) => e.id).indexOf(chunkId);

        //Checking if either it's the first chunk or the previous chunk has completed
        if(trackIndex !== 0){
          const prevChunk = this.chunkTracker.filter((e) => e.id === (chunkId-1))
          if (prevChunk[0].complete) {
            shouldExecute = true;
          }
        } else {
          shouldExecute = true;
        }

        //THIS IS THE ACTUAL WEB AUDIO API STUFF
        if (shouldExecute) {
          if (this.freeTime === null) {
            this.freeTime = this.context.currentTime
          }
          const source = this.context.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = buffer
          source.connect(this.context.destination)
          if (this.context.currentTime >= this.freeTime){
            source.start()
            this.freeTime = this.context.currentTime + buffer.duration
          } else {
            source.start(this.freeTime)
            this.freeTime += buffer.duration
          }
          //Update the tracker of the chunks that this one is complete
          this.chunkTracker[trackIndex] = {id: chunkId, complete: true}
        } else {
          //If the previous chunk hasn't processed yet, check again in 50ms
          setTimeout((passBuffer) => {
            decodeCallback(passBuffer)
          },50,buffer);
        }
      }
      decodeCallback.bind(this);
      
      this.context.decodeAudioData(chunk,decodeCallback);
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As an outline of how my environment is set up, I am storing the music files as MP3s which I have uploaded into a MongoDB database using GridFS.

You can do this if you want, but these days we have tools like Minio, which can make this easier using more common APIs.

> I then use a socket.io server to download the chunks from the MongoDB database and send them as individual emits to the front end

Don't go this route.  There's no reason for the overhead of web sockets, or Socket.IO.  A normal HTTP request would be fine.

> where the are processed by the Web Audio API and scheduled to play.

You can't stream this way.  The Web Audio API doesn't support useful streaming, unless you happened to have raw PCM chunks, which you don't.

> As far as I can tell, they are all scheduled right up next to each other so I can't find a reason why there should be any sort of gap or overlap between them.

Lossy codecs aren't going to give you sample-accurate output.  Especially with MP3, if you give it some arbitrary number of samples, you're going to end up with at least one full MP3 frame (~576 samples) output.  The reality is that you need data ahead of the first audio frame for it to work properly.  If you want to decode a stream, you need a stream to start with.  You can't independently decode MP3 this way.

Fortunately, the solution also simplifies what you're doing.  Simply return an HTTP stream from your server, and use an HTML audio element `<audio>` or `new Audio(url)`.  The browser will handle all the buffering.  Just make sure your server handles range requests, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for all of this info!  I just started learning how to do this bit yesterday, so I knew there were probably some things I would need to change up.  This answers my question, at least for now, but to be clear the reason for the skipping is the lossy format? Out of curiosity, If I used a format like WAV do you think that would fix the issue?

Comment: @MattHauff Technically, you still can't schedule in a sample-accurate way... you can only set a very precise timestamp and hope that it rounds onto the correct sample that you want.  If you had raw floating point PCM samples in the correct sample rate, you could use the ScriptProcessorNode to play them.  Of course then you'd also have to handle all the buffering and other logic yourself.  There are use cases for this method, but yours doesn't sound like one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I understand I was just curious.  Thanks for the help, I already implemented your solution and it's WAY easier and took 1/10th the time.

Comment: @MattHauff Cool, glad you found it helpful!  Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you want, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as "accepted", which will make it easier to find for future folks that come across your question.